# Output after multiplication shows weird characters, JAVA

Tags: java, character, output, multiplication

Hello fellow programmers.

Maybe it's a trivial question, yet I cant figure out solution, neither I can find any clue how to solve this. If its double post I am really sorry.

Here's the code: !! Don't forget to import your "java.util.Scanner" !!

```
double id[]=new double[4];
double price[]=new double[4];
String productName[]=new String[4];
id[0]=10001;
id[1]=10002;
id[2]=10003;
id[3]=10004;
price[0]=20;
price[1]=25;
price[2]=40;
price[3]=10;
productName[0]="T-Shirt";
productName[1]="More expensive T-Shirt";
productName[2]="Jacket";
productName[3]="Singlet";
int x=0;
int z=0;
int options;
double discount;

    System.out.println("Type in number of your choice between 1 to 4");
Scanner menu = new Scanner(System.in);          
options = menu.nextInt();

do {
System.out.println("Chosen product n.: "+ options);
}while (x > 0);

switch (options){ 
    case 1:
        System.out.println("Id of product: " + id[0] + " " + "Product price:"  +price[0] + " " + "Name of product: " + productName[0]);
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println("Id of product: " + id[1] + " " + "Product price: " +price[1] + " " + "Name of product: " + productName[1]);
        break;
    case 3:
        System.out.println("Id of product: " + id[2] + " " + "Product price: " +price[2] + " " + "Name of product: " + productName[2]);
        break;
    case 4:
        System.out.println("Id of product: " + id[3] + " " + "Product price: " +price[3] + " " + "Name of product: " + productName[3]);
        break;
                }
discount=idPrice(price);    
    System.out.println("Price after discount: " + price);
}
static double idPrice(double finalPrice[])
{
return (finalPrice[1]/0.8);
}
}
```

Here's the output after typing number 1:

```
Type in number of your choice between 1 to 4
1
Chosen product n.: 1
Id of product: 10001.0 Product price: 20.0 Name of product: T-Shirt
Price after discount: [D@3590efa8
```

As you can see the Price after discount is a mess. It should output number 20(25*0.8 (Hell yea 20% discount)).

That's the first question.

Next thing is. How can I spicify which finalPrice will be multiplied?

Thank you all. Hope it will be helpfull to someone else also.

Comment: ```price``` will print the reference to the array, not the elements. You should iterate over the items in the price[]. It is a very bad design anyway. You should create a ```Product``` class with variables id, price and productName and store the values as instances of Product.

Comment: Thank you for you comment. Was on your mind to use multidimensional array? like product[id][price][name]  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're printing an array, not it's elements.

In order to do so, you have to iterate through them:

```
for (double d : prices) {
    System.out.println(d);
}
```

**Edit**:
After reading the comments, you should print the `discount` variable:

```
System.out.println("Price after discount: " + discount);
```

Comment: If you add this to my code the output will be 
20.0
25.0
40.0
10.0
and not the number*0.8

Comment: As I can see from your source code, you have defined the `discount` variable

Comment: xD sorry, I had 1 } more than I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("Price after discount: " + price);
         Print Array of double------------------^
```

You need to iterate to print the price array like below

```
        for (double d : price) {
            System.out.println("Price is "+d);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `java.util.Arrays.toString(price)` to get a readable result.
What you are getting now is the default toString method of the Object object:

```
 public String toString() {
     return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
 }
```